# Postfix: Transport Maps via Third-Party Relay Host

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record

I have my website and email hosted with a shared host. Unfortunately their servers are using CPanel, so they are limited in their spam protection options.

I also have a VPS that I use for testing and hosting several other bits and pieces (Why don't I use the VPS for websites? I don't want to have to worry about backups!) - I can potentially use this as my MX for my domains, with the shared host as transport maps - I used to run my own dedi and so have Puppet modules ready to go for a mailserver.

The VPS host requires me to use a Postfix mail relay to make sure I'm not spamming from their IP ranges.

**Can I use Postfix's `transport_maps` and `relay_host` directives together to make my MX forward all mail for my domains to the shared host, but via the VPS host's relay?**

A further example of my desired outcome:

- `example.com` has an single MX record (for sanity) of `vps.example.com`
- `vps.example.com` receives incoming mail, then consults `transport_maps` and forwards it to the eventual destination `sharedhost.example.com`, using the the relay `relayvps.example.net` as the "next hop"

Comment: It's possible but will be pretty ugly if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah I gathered that it wouldn't be pretty, it's already a non-ideal situation to begin with! I've enquired about the possibility of bypassing the VPS host's relay, but I'm not hopeful. Could you add some detail in an answer about how it's possible?

Comment: There you go, you asked for it ;)

Comment: @Ismooth : I agree.

Comment: @lsmooth - thanks, I was thinking that would be the only option, thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't want to do this. But you could use forwarding addresses on your VPS like this:

```
a@example.org -> a@subdomain.example.org
b@example.org -> b@subdomain.example.org
...
```

Then configure your shared host as MX for subdomain.example.org. Then use `transport_maps`

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

in `/etc/postfix/transport` put

```
@subdomain.example.org smtp:[vps.relay.tld]
```

use `postmap` to update the lookup-table in transport.db with `postmap /etc/postfix/transport`.

If you need credentials for the relay you can configure them in `/etc/postfix/saslpass`

```
vps.relay.tld username:password
```

and use `postmap /etc/postfix/saslpass` to create/update the lookup-table.

On the shared host add the subdomains and forward the mail back to the original addresses. I'm not sure though if the forwarding wouldn't break spam-protection on the VPS.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you need a little bit of scripting on both side.

Without scripting you can't do this, if it could be done, it were a serious security flaw (f.e. mails could be sent directly to internal servers behind firewalls).

The simplest scripting solution were if you packaged the mail to send into another mail as attachment, and sent to the target. On the target it were waited by a .procmailrc or same like, which extracted the attachment and putted it into the outgoing mail queue of the target. I did both side in perl.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my question - I essentially want to say to my MTA "deliver messages to these domains to this destination, *but* via this relay". My understanding is that the relay would look up the MX for the destination, and would end up sending the mail back to the original server.

Comment: I'd also dispute that it's a security flaw. Any (good) mailserver admin will restrict access to their own domains and will know better than to commit the ultimate sin of running an open relay. I don't mind using the intermediate relay if it's part of my provider's infrastructure. Sending mails to internal servers behind firewalls would actually be relatively useful (one MTA to filter spam/viruses on the ingress and a farm of mailbox servers) as long as the ingress MTA was configured to respond correctly.